# Is "this" cached locally?

Tags: javascript, performance, caching, scope

It's [recommended](http://www.slideshare.net/madrobby/extreme-javascript-performance) to cache globals locally for better performance like so:

```
function showWindowSize() {
    var w = window;
    var width = w.innerWidth;
    var height = w.innerHeight;
    alert("width: " + width + " height: " + height);
}
```

Is the same true when using the "this" keyword, or is it cached already?

Example:

```
Game.prototype.runGameLoop = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.update();
  self.draw();
};
```

Comment: I think the recommendation is for when you're using the global reference a lot of times. meaning, using `var h = window.innerHeight;` is only valueable if you're using window.innerHeight inside a loop. if you use it only once, you can lose the local variable..

Comment: You seem to got that recommendation wrong. You definitely don't need a variable for `window`, and those `width` and `height` vars are only of use if they were used more than once, e.g. in a loop.

Comment: @Bergi I think I read the recommendation correct, although the original text could be wrong? From [another source](http://oreilly.com/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html): "store any out-of-scope variables in a local variable whenever it’s used more than once".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol `this` is always a local reference, so there's no need to "cache" it *for performance reasons.* There may be other reasons to preserve its value in another local variable however. When there's a local function that needs access to the `this` value from its containing function, then the containing function must make a copy of the value, since `this` is always set upon any function invocation.

(It may not be purely accurate to call `this` a "local reference"; the point is that the keyword always references a value pertinent to the local function activation record.)